# Converter Double para Inteiro

Tags: java, android, string, conversão-de-tipo

Gostaria que na `TextView` onde aparece o valor de "árvores a repor" o valor aparecesse sem ponto, nem zeros. Na situação abaixo aparece "180.0000000" e deveria aparecer "180".Ele é do tipo `Double`, e gostaria que aparecesse no tipo Inteiro. Já tentei converter usando a classe o método `Format`, da classe `String`, mas nada resolvido até agora

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: E porque você faria isto? Qualquer uso de `double` para valor monetário está errado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101.

Answer (score 2):

Vê se te ajuda esse exemplo.

```
double pi = 3.14159;
int i = (int)pi;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Já tentei converter usando a classe o método `Format`, da classe `String`

Que também funciona, assim como a reposta do @RenanOsorio.

Utilizando [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) precisa apenas de definir o formatador como `%.0f` para mostrar sem nenhuma casa decimal:

```
double arvoresRepor = ...;
TextView textArvoresRepor = findViewById(...);

textArvoresRepor.setText(String.format("%.0f", arvoresRepor));
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o `NumberFormat` e no `onCreate()` você inicializa e configura ele e depois, usa esse objeto para formatar os números.
Por exemplo:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    NumberFormat f;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

    f = NumberFormat.getNumberInstace();
    f.setMaximumFractionDigits(2); //No máximo 2 casas decimais

    //Inicialização da sua TextView e outros códigos...

    textArvoresRepor.setText(f.format(arvoresRepor)); //definindo o texto e formatando o mesmo.


    }

}
```

**Detalhe:** o NumberFormat é do pacote `java.text`;
Por isso, você vai ter que importar ele.

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado!!